# Appended span tags don't have assigned text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to iterate over a collection of checked checkboxes and append the text of each checked box to a div as a span. I've tried this with option tags to a select and it works fine, but when doing it with span tags, the text doesn't seem to be showing.

```
$.each(elms, function(index, value) {
    var textVal;
    textVal = $.trim($(value).parent().text());
    return $('#narrowSic').append($('<span class=label>', {
        text: textVal
    }));
});​
```

This is the HTML that it's being used with:

```
  <div id="filteredSicDiv">
        <a href="javascript: void(0)">Clear</a>
        <div id="narrowSic" class="labelParent">
                  Sic:</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: use complete tags, `$('<span class=label></span>'`

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using this on?

Comment: @KevinB I added the closing portion of the tag, but am still getting span elements without any text

Comment: Updated initial post with the HTML

Comment: I don't think `text` is supported anymore.

Comment: Can you show the part of your code where you assign value to "elms"?

Comment: Yup, I've just checked the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/). They're not mentioning `text` as an option anymore.

Comment: @adnan text is still supported, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: @SCS - You mentioned something about checkboxes, yet i see no checkboxes in your html.

Comment: @KevinB, can you please fiddle me an example of `text` working with `append()`? thank you

Comment: @adnan it isn't append we're working with. .append() is appending a span in this case, not text. The span contains the text.

Comment: @KevinB, I see. Apparently I was confused about DOM elements creation with JQuery. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @adnan Ah i see the issue. It's the `class=label`. If you removed that and added `"class":"label"` after `text:textVal` it would work. See artlung's answer for more information.

Comment: @Adnan, `append()` was not the culprit. The documentation says: "the second argument to jQuery() can accept a map consisting of a superset of the properties that can be passed to the `.attr()` method. Furthermore, any event type can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: `val`, `css`, `html`, `text`, `data`, `width`, `height`, or `offset`. The name `"class"` must be quoted in the map since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and `"className"` cannot be used since it is not the correct attribute name." This is from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 that @KevinB linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the text with the `.text()` function:

```
$.each(elms, function(index, value) {
     var textVal;
     textVal = $.trim($(value).parent().text());
     return $('#narrowSic').append($('<span class="label">').text(textVal));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe for the tricky part, the code you actually want is something like *note I'm appending to the body for debugging*:

```
$(document.body).append($('<span />', {
    "text": textVal,
    "class": 'label'
}));​
```

See the jQuery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 and note this caveat:

> *When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM
>   that exactly replicates the HTML source provided.*

So your updated snippet is:

```
$.each(elms, function(index, value) {
    var textVal = $.trim($(value).parent().text());
    return $('#narrowSic').append($('<span />', {
        "text": textVal,
        "class": 'label'
    }));
});
```

This presumes that in all cases, your value of `textVal` is working as you expect.

Comment: I tried out royh's answer and it worked, but this was much closer to what I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @SCS Cool. The general principle is when building an element with jQuery. start with a bare tag, and build it up, whether with the parameter as you have done, or with the standard `text()`, `css()`, `attr()` mechanisms, then append. It's simpler and more compatible.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(elms, function(index, value) { 
    var textVal; 
    textVal = $.trim($(value).parent().text()); 
    $('#narrowSic').append($('<span class=label>' + textVal + '</span>')); 
});
```